# Create using blocks for multiple objects in collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, using

Given the following code:

```
using (payment.GetModifyLock())
{
    foreach (var paymentItem in paymentItems)
    {
        using (paymentItem.GetModifyLock())
        {
            
        }
    }
    DoAction();
}
```

I'm looking to modify this code so that `DoAction` is done inside all the using blocks (not just one).  If the collection contains two items, I'd want it to function in this way:

```
using(payment.GetModifyLock())
using(paymentItem1.GetModifyLock())
using(paymentItem2.GetModifyLock())
{
    DoAction();
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to create a more reusable version of what you have, you can wrap the functionality into an IDisposable helper class.  This is naïve and not recommended for production code, but it is a simple, reusable abstraction.

```
public class NestedLocker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _parentLocker;
    private readonly Queue<IDisposable> _childLockers = new Queue<IDisposable>();
    
    public NestedLocker(Func<IDisposable> parentLocker, 
        IEnumerable<Func<IDisposable>> childLockers)
    {
        _parentLocker = parentLocker();
        
        foreach (var childLocker in childLockers)
        {
            _childLockers.Enqueue(childLocker());
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var childLocker in _childLockers)
        {
            childLocker.Dispose();
        }
        
        _parentLocker.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can test it with the following:

```
void Main()
{
    Func<IDisposable> parentLocker = () => new ParentLocker();
    List<Func<IDisposable>> childLockers = 
        new List<Func<IDisposable>> { () => new ChildLocker(), () => new ChildLocker() };
    using (new NestedLocker(parentLocker, childLockers))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("action");
    }
}

public class ParentLocker : IDisposable
{
    public ParentLocker()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent locker created");
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent locker disposed");
    }
}

public class ChildLocker : IDisposable
{
    public ChildLocker()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child locker created");
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child locker disposed");
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
Parent locker created
Child locker created
Child locker created
action
Child locker disposed
Child locker disposed
Parent locker disposed
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've figured this out using this code:

```
using (payment.GetModifyLock())
{
    var locks = new List<DistributedLock>();
    try
    {
        foreach (var paymentItem in paymentItems)
        {
            locks.Add(paymentItem.GetModifyLock());
        }

        // Do action
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var locker in locks)
        {
            locker.Dispose(); ;
        }
    }
}
```